# What is the use of QName and Operator class?

Tags: java, java-me, stub, jsr172, qnames

Can anyone explain what is the use of QName, Operation and Stub class in J2ME by giving simple and understandable examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use before. See the following java documents. May be it will helps you.

- [QName](http://martin.melkovic.sk/wtk22.docs.api/j2me-rpc/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html)
- [Operation](http://martin.melkovic.sk/wtk22.docs.api/j2me-rpc/javax/microedition/xml/rpc/Operation.html)
- [Stub](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/ws/jsr172/javax/xml/rpc/Stub.html)